# How to propagate allChecked in generic table component with checkboxes

Tags: angular

I have a generic table component which is used in several places.  One of the options for the the table is `showCheckboxes`.  When `showCheckboxes` is true, a column is added to the table containing a checkbox for each data item (i.e. each row below the table header).  The checkboxes emit events back to the parent.  When receiving these events, the parent typically makes a database update or some other parent-specific action which the generic table component is not concerned with.

The team has decided that when the table has checkboxes, there should also be a checkbox in the table header row which does "check all" kind of things.  This "check all" checkbox doesn't necessarily need to fire events to the parent, providing the individual item checkboxes can still do that.

What would be the high-level approach to this?  A colleague suggested it should be done via the model with a piece of code in the consuming form.  I want to avoid having to write anything in the parents though, because this is supposed to be a generic compnent providing generic behaviour.  As long as the individual checkboxes still fire their events to the parent, all our requirements for database updates, etc. can be met.

I'm really not sure what code would be helpful here (completely new to Angular), so here's the table component, html first...

```html
<table
  mat-table
  matSort
  [dataSource]="tableData"
  (matSortChange)="onSortChange($event)"
  [ngClass]="{'background-secondary': colorScheme === 'secondary'}"
  [attr.aria-label]="ariaLabel"
>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="checkbox">
    <th
      [ngClass]="{'header-secondary': colorScheme === 'secondary'}"
      *matHeaderCellDef
      mat-header-cell
    >
      <!-- check-them-all checkbox -->
      <mat-checkbox
        *ngIf="showCheckboxes"
        (change)="onSelectAllCheckboxClick($event)"
      ></mat-checkbox>      
    </th>
    <td
      [ngClass]="{'cell-secondary': colorScheme === 'secondary'}"
      mat-cell
      *matCellDef="let element; let i = index"
    >
      <ng-container
        *ngIf="checkBoxFormGroupParent; else noFormGroupParent"
        [formGroup]="checkBoxFormGroupParent"
      >
        <ng-container [formGroupName]="element[formGroupFieldName]">
          <mat-checkbox
            formControlName="checked"
            (change)="onCheckboxClick($event, element)"
          ></mat-checkbox>
          <span>{{element[formGroupFieldName].id}}</span>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #noFormGroupParent>
        <mat-checkbox (change)="onCheckboxClick($event, element)"></mat-checkbox>
      </ng-template>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container
    *ngFor="let column of columns"
    [matColumnDef]="column.name"
  >
    <ng-container *ngIf="column.sortable; else notSortable">
      <th
        mat-sort-header
        [ngClass]="{'header-secondary': colorScheme === 'secondary'}"
        mat-header-cell
        *matHeaderCellDef
      >
        {{ column.name }}
      </th>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #notSortable>
      <th
        [ngClass]="{'header-secondary': colorScheme === 'secondary'}"
        mat-header-cell
        *matHeaderCellDef
      >
        {{ column.name }}
      </th>
    </ng-template>
    <td
      mat-cell
      class="table__cell"
      *matCellDef="let element"
      [ngClass]="{
        'table-cell--highlighted': column.highlighted,
        'cell-secondary': colorScheme === 'secondary'
      }"
    >
      <app-table-cell-data
        [tableElement]="element[column.field]"
        [column]="column"
        [dateFormat]="dateFormat"
        (linkClick)="onLinkClick(element)"
      ></app-table-cell-data>
      <ng-container *ngIf="column.subTitle">
        <p class="sub-title" *ngIf="element[column.subTitle]">
        {{ column.subTitle }}: {{ element[column.subTitle] }}
      </p>
      <p class="sub-title" *ngIf="column.subField && element[column.subField]?.length">
        {{ column.subTitle }}: {{ element[column.subField] }}
      </p>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container
        *ngIf="column.showRadioButton && radioFormGroupParent && radioControlName"
        [formGroup]="radioFormGroupParent"
      >
        <mat-radio-button
          class="radio__button"
          [checked]="radioFormGroupParent.get(radioControlName)?.value === element['name']"
          (change)="onRadioChange(element['name'])"
        ></mat-radio-button>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container
        *ngIf="column.showCheckbox && checkBoxFormGroupParent"
        [formGroup]="checkBoxFormGroupParent"
      >
        <ng-container [formGroupName]="element[formGroupFieldName]">
          <mat-checkbox
            class="checkbox"
            formControlName="checked"
          ></mat-checkbox>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container
    *ngFor="let action of actions"
    [matColumnDef]="action.name"
  >
    <th
      [ngClass]="{'header-secondary': colorScheme === 'secondary'}"
      mat-header-cell
      *matHeaderCellDef
    ></th>
    <td
      [ngClass]="{'cell-secondary': colorScheme === 'secondary'}"
      class="table__action-cell"
      mat-cell
      *matCellDef="let element"
      [id]="action"
    >
      <ng-container *ngIf="action.showFlatButton; else iconButton">
        <app-button
          #flatButton
          appearance="secondary"
          class="table__button--flat"
          (click)="onActionClick(action.name, element)"
          [label]="action.name"
          [prefix]="action.icon"
          [buttonId]="element[buttonIdfieldName]"
        ></app-button>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-template #iconButton>
        <app-icon-button
          *ngIf="!action.showDropdown; else iconButtonWithMenu"
          [ariaLabel]="action.name"
          [ngClass]="{'table__action-button--single': actions?.length === 1}"
          [buttonIcon]="action.icon"
          [iconColor]="actionIconColor"
          [matTooltip]="action.tooltip ?? ''"
          (buttonClicked)="onActionClick(action.name, element)"
        ></app-icon-button>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template #iconButtonWithMenu>
        <app-icon-button
          *ngIf="dropDownMenu && action.showDropdown"
          ariaLabel="Dropdown menu"
          [ngClass]="{'table__action-button--single': actions?.length === 1}"
          [buttonIcon]="action.icon"
          [iconColor]="actionIconColor"
          [matTooltip]="action.tooltip ?? ''"
          [matMenuTriggerFor]="dropDownMenu"
          (buttonClicked)="onActionClick(action.name, element)"
        ></app-icon-button>
      </ng-template>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr
    mat-header-row
    *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"
  ></tr>
  <tr
    mat-row
    *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
  ></tr>
</table>

<mat-paginator
  *ngIf="showPaginator"
  [pageSize]="pageSize"
  [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
  [length]="tableData.data.length"
></mat-paginator>
```

... and the table component .ts ...

```js
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  Output,
  QueryList,
  ViewChild,
  ViewChildren,
} from '@angular/core';
import {UntypedFormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatMenu} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatCheckboxChange} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatSort, Sort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import {ActionColumn} from '@Shared/component-library/interfaces/action-column';
import {TableColumn} from '@Shared/component-library/interfaces/table-column';
import {TableActionEvent} from '@Shared/component-library/interfaces/events/table-action-event';
import {TableLinkClickEvent} from '@Shared/component-library/interfaces/events/table-link-click-event';
import {ButtonComponent} from '@Shared/component-library/components/atoms/buttons/action-button/button.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss'],
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator?: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
  @ViewChildren('flatButton') flatButtons?: QueryList<ButtonComponent>;

  @Input() columns: TableColumn[] = [];
  @Input() actions?: ActionColumn[];
  @Input() actionIconColor = 'primary';
  @Input() showPaginator = false;
  @Input() showCheckboxes = false;
  @Input() colorScheme = '';
  @Input() formGroupParent?: UntypedFormGroup;
  @Input() checkBoxFormGroupParent?: UntypedFormGroup;
  @Input() controlName = '';
  @Input() formGroupFieldName = '';
  @Input() radioFormGroupParent?: UntypedFormGroup;
  @Input() radioControlName?: string;
  @Input() ariaLabel = 'table';
  @Input() dropDownMenu?: MatMenu;
  @Input() dateFormat = 'd MMM YYY h:mma';
  @Input() buttonIdfieldName = '';
  @Input() filterByColumn = '';

  @Output() actionClicked = new EventEmitter<TableActionEvent>();
  @Output() checkboxClicked = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() radioValue = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() linkClick = new EventEmitter<TableLinkClickEvent>();
  @Output() sortEvent = new EventEmitter();

  tableData = new MatTableDataSource<unknown>([]);
  displayedColumns: string[] = [];
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [5, 10, 25, 100];
  pageSize = 5;
  length = this.tableData.data.length;

  @Input() set dataSource(data: unknown[] | null) {
    if (data) {
      this.setDataSource(data);
    }
  }

  @Input() set columnsToDisplay(columns: string[]) {
    this.displayedColumns = columns;
  }

  @Input() set searchTerm(searchTerm: string) {
    this.tableData.filter = searchTerm.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let columnNames;
    if (this.displayedColumns.length > 0) {
      columnNames = this.displayedColumns;
    } else {
      columnNames = this.columns.map((column) => column.name);
    }

    let actionNames: string[] = [];
    if (this.actions) {
      actionNames = this.actions.map((action) => action.name);
    }

    this.displayedColumns = [...columnNames, ...actionNames];

    if (this.showCheckboxes) {
      this.displayedColumns = ['checkbox', ...this.displayedColumns];
    }

    if (this.filterByColumn) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
      this.tableData.filterPredicate = (data: any, filter: string) => {
        return data[this.filterByColumn].toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1;
      };
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.setPaginator(this.paginator);
  }

  setPaginator(paginator: MatPaginator | undefined): void {
    if (paginator) {
      this.tableData.paginator = paginator;
    }
  }

  setDataSource(data: unknown[]): void {
    this.tableData = new MatTableDataSource<unknown>(data);
    this.setPaginator(this.paginator);
  }

  onActionClick(action: string, element: unknown): void {
    this.actionClicked.emit({action, tableElement: element});
  }

  onSortChange(event: Sort) {
    this.sortEvent.emit(event);
  }

  onLinkClick(element: unknown): void {
    this.linkClick.emit({tableElement: element});
  }

  onCheckboxClick(checkboxEvent: MatCheckboxChange, element: object): void {
    this.checkboxClicked.emit({checkBox: checkboxEvent, data: element});
  }

  onRadioChange(element: string): void {
    this.radioValue.emit(element);
  }

  onSelectAllCheckboxClick(checkboxEvent: MatCheckboxChange): void {
    const tableDataLocal = this.tableData;
    const columns = this.columns;
    // const x = Object.keys(this.formGroupParent?.controls);
    console.log(checkboxEvent);
    const x = this.formGroupParent;
    const y = this.checkBoxFormGroupParent;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you can use

```
   onSelectAllCheckboxClick(checkboxEvent: MatCheckboxChange): void {
      const tableDataLocal = this.tableData.data.forEach(x=>{
      this.onCheckboxClick(checkboxEvent,x)
    }
```

BTW really I don't know the necesary of use a FormGroup or a FormArray, you can add to your data source a new property "checked" and use [(ngModel)]

```
  <ng-container
    *ngIf="checkBoxFormGroupParent; else noFormGroupParent"
  >
    <ng-container >
      <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="element.checkbox"
      ></mat-checkbox>
      <span>{{element[formGroupFieldName].id}}</span>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
```

And you use in ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(){
   ...
   if (this.showCheckboxes) {
      this.dataSource.data.forEach(x=>{
         x.checkbox=false;
      })
      this.displayedColumns = ['checkbox', ...this.displayedColumns];
 
   }
   ...
}
```